# C++ Winsock2 sending integers with byte order

Tags: c++, sockets

I have been looking for a way to have an integer sent over a Windows Socket using Winsock2. I have looked at most, if not all, of the questions people have asked on stackoverflow already.

This is what I have for the client, that sends the integer:

```
struct struct_var
{
    int Packet;
    int Number;
};

struct_var *arraystruct;

arraystruct = (struct_var *) malloc(sizeof(struct_var));
(*arraystruct).Packet = 100;
(*arraystruct).Number = 150;
int bytes = send(client,(char*)arraystruct,sizeof(*arraystruct),0);`
```

I have also tried to send using:

```
int int_data = 4;
int bytes = send(server, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);`
```

This was recommended on another stackoverflow question
This is the receiving side, which was also recommended:

```
int int_data;
int bytes = recv(server, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);
cout << int_data;`
```

When I run these the output I get from command line is: `-858993460`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I would also like it to have the correct byte order as this will be sent over multiple kinds of computers.
Thanks in advance who can help me out

Full Server Code:

```
int main() {
WSADATA wsaData;
WORD version;
int error;

version = MAKEWORD(2, 0);

error = WSAStartup(version, &wsaData);

if ( error != 0 )
{
    return FALSE;
}

if ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ||
     HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 0 )
{
    WSACleanup();
    return FALSE;
}


SOCKET server;

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

sockaddr_in sin;

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(5555);

if (bind( server, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) == SOCKET_ERROR ){
    DWORD ec=WSAGetLastError();
    cerr << hex << "bind ERROR" << ec << endl;
    return FALSE;
}

if ( listen( server, SOMAXCONN ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    DWORD ec=WSAGetLastError();
    cerr << hex << "listen ERROR" << ec << endl;
    return FALSE;
}

SOCKET client;
int length;

    while(1) {

    if ( listen( server, SOMAXCONN ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    DWORD ec=WSAGetLastError();
    cerr << hex << "listen ERROR" << ec << endl;
    return FALSE;
    }

    length = sizeof sin;
    client = accept( server, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, &length );
    cout << "Client connected" << endl;
    cout << "Sending Instructions..." << endl;

    int int_data;
    int bytes;

    bytes = recv(client, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);

    cout << int_data << endl;
}
```

}

}

Full Client Code:

```
int main() {

WSADATA wsaData;
WORD version;
int error;

version = MAKEWORD(2, 0);

error = WSAStartup(version, &wsaData);

if ( error != 0 )
{
    return FALSE;
}

if ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ||
     HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 0 )
{
    WSACleanup();
    return FALSE;
}

SOCKET client;

client = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

sockaddr_in sin;

memset( &sin, 0, sizeof sin );

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
sin.sin_port = htons(5555);

if ( connect(client, (SOCKADDR*)(&sin), sizeof sin ) == SOCKET_ERROR ){
    return FALSE;
}

int int_data = 4;
    int bytes = send(client, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);
```

}

Comment: `-858993460` is `0xCCCCCCCC`, a value sometimes used to flag uninitialized integers in debug builds.

Comment: Do `cout << bytes` to make sure you received the data!

Comment: This means, that you didn't receive any data - so the problem lies in a part of the code not shown ... `connect()` or friends

Comment: client = accept( server, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, &length );
    cout << "Client connected" << endl;
    cout << "Sending Instructions..." << endl;`

Comment: -1 means the socket is invalid.  Did you correctly initialize, bind(), and accept() that socket before calling recv()?  My psychic powers tell me that you are trying to recv() on the listen socket used to accept the incoming connection, instead of the socket returned by accept().

Comment: Why is the server doing "while (listen(...) = SOCKET_ERROR);" ? And why is the code Starting from accept() enclose d in a while loop? These are unusual structures.

Comment: I don't know why the first is enclosed got the code from elsewhere. Should I get rid of it?

Comment: accept is in while so it accepts multiple connections

Comment: Your style odf server would typically have loops in certain places, but that while statement will loop as long as listen returns an error. As a general diagnostic I would take each of your sockets calls and recode them to have an error check followed by a call to WSAGetLastError and print the code from that and exit the app. For example, if (listen(...) == SOCKET_ERROR) { DWORD ec=WSAGetLastError(); cerr << hex << "listen ERROR " << ec << endl; return false; }

Comment: Apologies for my spelling errors. The loop you need should enclose listen, too. For each connection, listen rerturns success, you then call accept to get the client-specific handle, then receive the request, do what it calls for, close the handle you got from accept, then go back and listen.

Comment: Thanks, Check the updated code. Like that?

Comment: You have a call to listen that, when it succeeds, will be ignored, before the while loop. Apart from that, you should be getting error codes when things go wrong, which you can look up in MSDN. My final suggestion is to google for simple chat server and client, and build that as a tutorial. This is a wheel that should not be reinvented, just retyped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
int bytes = recv(server, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Should be:

```
int bytes = recv(client, (char*) &int_data, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL);
```

A few other nitpicky things, that aren't causing your problem, but you should know:

1. Don't bind your server socket to 10.0.0.5.  Bind to 0 (INADDR_ANY).  That way, your code still works when you run it on machine who's IP addrss is 10.0.0.6.
2. Use htonl(), htons(), ntohs(), and ntohl() for interoperating with big-endian boxes.
3. Always check the return values from socket calls.  If recv returns 0 or -1, it means the remote side has disconnected. (0 technically means the client has stopped sending, but unless you are doing shutdown half-close stuff, it means he disconnected).
4. TCP sockets are not message oriented, they are stream oriented.  That is, just because you tell recv() to get N bytes, doesn't mean it will return N bytes.  IP fragmentation, TCP segmentations, and other factors can make recv() return partial data.  Use the MSG_WAITALL flag as appropriate.

Comment: Your full code above has the exact same problem.  Trying to call recv() on the listen socket instead of the socket returned by accept().

Comment: If I change it to that I no longer get connection

Comment: It already is at the listen socket being `server`. Changing to `client` results in no connection

Comment: How would changing the socket you recv on have an impact on the socket you are connecting on?  Probably with all the stopping and starting of your server, your port is still in a TIME_WAIT state.  Wait 2 minutes (or reboot), and all will be well.  You must call recv() on the socket returned by accept.  It won't work any other way.

Comment: Command line still outputs `-858993460`. Along with `-1` bytes

Comment: I just compiled your code as you have it above.  Seems to work fine since you adopted most of my suggestions.  To address #4 above, you can just MSG_WAITALL flag on recv().

Answer (score 1):

You're making this almost impossible on yourself. Instead of starting with code, start with a protocol specification. You can look at the specifications of existing protocols that use TCP, such as HTTP, IMAP, and so on, to see what a protocol specification should include.

The protocol specification should explain everything that is sent or received at the *byte* level. It should explain how connections are established and torn down. It should explain how dead connections are detected from either end. If the protocol has application-layer messages, it should explain how they are delimited and how the receiver finds the ends of messages. It should specify who transmits when.

Then, debugging is easy. Follow this flowchart:

1) Does the server follow the specification? If not, the server is broken.

2) Does the client follow the specification? If not, the client is broken.

3) If it still doesn't work, the specification is broken.

This makes it possible to ensure that the server and client work together. And when they don't, it makes it possible to know which side needs to be fixed.

It only take an hour or two to sketch out a protocol specification, and I promise you the time saved will be more than worth it. All it takes is one time you change the wrong end when something doesn't work (and then find lots of things are newly-broken because you fixed one of the places that was right) to pay for the time taken. Plus, as a bonus, it is then possible to make other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this problem as well and I noticed that my client wasn't even connecting.

Try to save the value returned by connect() and recv() making sure its > -1 or print out some error.